# Partition offset at 63, 64, 2048 or 4096?

Tags: partitioning, ssd, openbsd

I did not wish to use the entire SSD for OpenBSD 5.5. (The SSD is new and pre-formatted with MSDOS using Gparted)

During installation and at the fdisk stage, I chose Partition #: 0 to install OpenBSD (I changed the Partition ID to a6). I plan to install other Unix-like OS in Partition #: 1 or 2.

When prompted for partition offset (the default is 0), what number should I enter: 0, 63, 64, 2048 or 4096?

Below are details about the disk geometry of my SSD when I entered 0 for Partition offset:

```
Use (W)hole disk or (E)dit the MBR? [whole] e

You will now create a single MBR partition to contain your OpenBSD data. This partition must have an id of ‘A6’; must *NOT* overlap other partitions;  and must be marked as the only active partition. Inside the fdisk command, the ‘manual’ command describes all the fdisk commands in detail.

Disk: sd0    geometry: 29185/255/63 [468862128 sectors)
Offset: 0    Signature: 0xAA55

                  Starting                Ending        LBA Info:                
 #:    id       C    H    S  -         C     H    S    [start : size]    
  0:   00       0    0    0 -          0     0    0    [0     : 0   ] unused
  1:   00       0    0    0  -         0     0    0    [0     : 0   ] unused
  2:   00       0    0    0  -         0     0    0    [0     : 0   ] unused
  3:   00       0    0    0  -         0     0    0    [0     : 0   ] unused

Enter ‘help’ for information
fdisk: 1> e 0

Partition id ('0' to disable) [0 - FF]: [0] (? for help) a6
Do you wish to edit in CHS mode? [n] no
Partition offset: [0] 0
Partition size: [0] 70g
fdisk:*1> f 0
Partition 0 marked active
fdisk:*1> q
Writing MBR at offset 0
The auto-allocated layout for sd0 is:
```

The installation proceeded smoothly without a hitch.

Upon rebooting my machine, the last few lines were the error messages:

```
root on sd0a swap on sd0b dump on sd0b
panic: root filesystem has size 0
Stopped at Debugger+0x5 : leave
Run at least 'trace' AND 'ps' AND INCLUDE OUTPUT WHEN REPORTING THIS PANIC! IF RUNNING SMP, USE 'mach ddbcpu <#>' AND 'trace' ON OTHER PROCESSORS TOO.
DO NOT EVEN BOTHER REPORTING THIS WITHOUT INCLUDING THAT INFORMATION!
ddb{0}>
```

Comment: Random question, were you able to run those two commands suggested?

Comment: @CanadianLuke: Why are you answering my question with a question?

Comment: It's a comment, not an answer. Offering ways to improve the question whenever possible is what comments can be used for. If I knew the answer off the top of my head, I'd post it, but this is simply a comment, that's it.